# How to handle errors using sscanf in a loop to get inputs from stdin?

Tags: c, error-handling, while-loop, scanf, stdin

I am writing a code to read inputs from the keyboard (stdin) and print them. The standard inputs are like the following.

```
(6, 10) (6, 12) (6, 20) (6, 25) (9, 25) (10,25)
```

The code is as below:

```
void main()
{
    int key, value;

    char input[1000]; //assume the input is than 1000 bits and initiate the inputs as strings
    char *pointer;
    int offset;

    printf("enter key-value pairs of integer numbers like (a,b)(c,d): ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    pointer = input;

    //read the pairs of values one at a time until the last pair
    //                       leave space before and after value and brackets to skip spaces
    while (sscanf(pointer, " ( %d , %d ) %n", &key, &value, &offset) == 2) 
    {
        printf("key is %d, value is %d", key, value);
        pointer = pointer + offset
    }
}
```

I also want to improve the code for error handling. For example, if the user inputs were like:

```
(6, 10) (6, 12) (6, ABC) (DEF, 25) (9, 25) (10,25)
```

I tried to add a `scanResult` after the while loop finishes, and clearly, it would not work as `scanResult` will be -1 once the last pair of values have been scanned.

```
void main()
{
    int key, value;

    char input[1000]; //assume the input is than 1000 bits and initiate the inputs as strings
    char *pointer;
    int offset;
    int scanResult;

    printf("enter key-value pairs of integer numbers like (a,b)(c,d): ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    pointer = input;

    //read the pairs of values one at a time until the last pair
    //                       leave space before and after value and brackets to skip spaces
    while ((scanResult = sscanf(pointer, " ( %d , %d ) %n", &key, &value, &offset)) == 2) 
    {
        printf("key is %d, value is %d", key, value);
        pointer = pointer + offset
    }
    
    if (scanfResult != 2)
    {
        printf("invalid input"); 
    }
return;
}
```

Could someone let me how to write the code for error handling?

Comment: Add a check for `scanfResult == EOF`? As in `if (scanResult != EOF && scanResult != 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
char *end = input + strlen(input);
```

and

```
while ( pointer < end && (2 == sscanf(pointer, " ( %d , %d ) %n", &key, &value, &offset)) )
```